# Detect changed input Values of an HTML input table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express-handlebars

Im trying to findout how i can Detect changed Values in the Following prefilled input Table. I get the Data from my MongoDB and use Express-Handlebars and nodejs to fill in the data to the HTML.

```
<form action="/someaction" method="post">
    <table class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
     <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>some setting</th>
         <th>some setting</th>
         <th>some setting</th>
         <th>some setting</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     {{# each values }}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> {{ this.name}} </td>
                <td><input type="string" style="position: relative;" name="some setting" value={{this.some setting}} autofocus></td>
                <td><input type="string" style="position: relative;" name="some setting" value={{ this.some setting}}></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="position: relative;" value="some setting" value={{ this.some setting}}></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="position: relative;" value="some setting" value={{ this.some setting}}></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="someid" value={{ this.some id}}>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    {{/each}}
   </table>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When i click the Submit button the server will recieve An object with all the configs . Which i then want to write back to the MongoDB. But I dont want to write unchanged Values back to it. I could iterate over the Object but as the Rows are basically unlimited that could lead to Server perfomance problems.

I wanted to know if there is away to detect if a value has changed in that specific row and mark it somehow in the Object my server recieves. That would allow me to just Iterate once over the whole Object and only write those Configs that changed.

I saw that there is some kind of onChanged thing in HTML or JS that could do that. But i only saw it beeing used for direct changes and I only want changes to be applied when the Button is pressed.

I would like to avoid Javascript tho if possible!

I hope I could somehow express what I want to achieve.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit aside, but HTML doesn't know an input of type of string. Should be type of text instead.

Comment: You won't be able to avoid javascript. you need too keep the old values and compare if the value has changed.

Comment: Should have added that i don't know muchabout HTML. I have the server and my mongodb and i try to make a frontend for it. It worked in my initial tests tho! But i'll change that THX!

Comment: Most likely "string" will work, since the type defaults to text if it's not defined. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) is a big help for issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mark each row with a [data-](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute and use it to check if it changes.

For example in a given row:

```
<tr id="tr1" data-foo-bar="original">
   <td><input type="text" onchange="change();"></td>
</tr>
```

When a value inside this row is changed you trigger this function:

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById("tr1").dataset.fooBar = "modified";
}
```

Then you can access this attribute with:

```
if (document.getElementById("tr1").dataset.fooBar == "original"){
    // hasn't been changed

}
else
{
    // it has changed

}
```

Comment: I have done something similar now. I use the get Element by id to change the value of a hidden input which i added to the table. Unfortunatly it always only changes the value of index 0 of the output object. Even if i changed something in the 3rd row or so. Also i need to be able to acces that data tag outside of the HTML in my nodejs server code. Which didn't work like you proposed it. Do you know how i can fix my issue ?

Comment: I proposed this answer hoping it'd be useful. Sorry I'm afraid I don't know enough to help you.

Comment: It did help a lot! I managed to give the id's a dinamic numbe rocresponding to their row. I then call the js with said index! And boom wha ti want is there.

Comment: Glad to hear ^_^